# How to get specified field value without ID in facebook graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using `facebook graph api` to get `ads` under a `account`

```
act_xxx/ads?fields=name
```

But it always returns with `ID` field which I really dont need

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Feed",
      "id": "xxxx"
    },
    {
      "name": "w",
      "id": "xxx"
    },
    {
      "name": "Grig",
      "id": "xxx"
    },
    {
      "name": "Bi ",
      "id": "xxxx"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "QVFIUlJnQ3dUbkIxWVNMsDSjhqSjBmNEhHSzBn",
      "after": "QVFIUnVJekJGc0xWphVXlCd3V1WEhkVjNR"
    }
  }
}
```

What I want is only field name

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Feed"
    },
    {
      "name": "w"
    },
    {
      "name": "Grig"
    },
    {
      "name": "Bi "
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "QVFIUlJnQ3dUbkIxWVNMsDSjhqSjBmNEhHSzBn",
      "after": "QVFIUnVJekJGc0xWphVXlCd3V1WEhkVjNR"
    }
  }
}
```

How Can I made it

Thanks

Comment: That's not possible, `id` is a default field you will always get, even if not explicitly asking for it.

Comment: It seems it always return ID of `node`. I want to filter ad under account of which the spend is over `5` and status is `ACTIVE`. When I use `account_id/ads` node it alwalys return ad_id back to me